# Is per-record timeline consistency is somehow equivalent to causal consistency?

Tags: distributed-systems

What I understand about per-record timeline consistency is:

> For a specific primary key all the insert/update/delete operations should
>   be read in the same order by all replicas.

Since all modifications to a specific primary key are causally related (a client reads it, then modifies or delete it), then per-record timeline consistency is somehow equivalent to causal consistency. If they are essentially equivalent, then why put another name on it? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may know that per-record timeline consistency is used in [PNUTS: Yahoo!’s Hosted Data Serving Platform](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/1/1454167.pdf):

> We provide per-record timeline consistency: all replicas of a given record apply all updates to the record in the same order.

**Answer your questions:**

> Since all modifications to a specific primary key are causally related (a client reads it, then modifies or delete it), ...

They are actually totally (or sequentially) ordered, stronger than "causally related".

> ... then per-record timeline consistency is somehow equivalent to causal consistency.

Given the reason above, per-record timeline consistency is more like [sequential consistency (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_consistency). In fact, per-record time consistency is also called per-key sequential consistency, which is stronger than per-key causal consistency. Because sequential consistency is not [local](https://aphyr.com/posts/333-serializability-linearizability-and-locality), per-key sequential consistency is not equivalent to (i.e., weaker than) sequential consistency defined over multiple keys.